# Data provided in the open graph tags does not render with the Like button

Tags: java, facebook-like

I would like the Like button on my web page to render like the one [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), where it shows an image, title and description below the comment box. I have included the necessary open graph tags, however the Like box is just the basic, out-of-the-box one, with none of the extra open graph information. Here is my code, as you can see I've redacted my FB application id, but otherwise this is what I'm running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="facebook" class="no_js" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
    <title>Facebook Test Page</title>
    <link ref="canonical" href="http://localhost/Fbtest.jsp" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<REDACTED>" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Facebook Test Page" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost/Fbtest.jsp" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://localhost/images/my_family.png" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Website" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is just a test page, for Facebook integration." />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"><!-- The JS SDK requires the fb-root element in order to load properly. --></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: '<REDACTED>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        };
        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
    </script>

    <h1>Facebook Test Page</h1>
    <p>Here is a picture of my family. This is just a test, for Facebook integration.</p>
    <img alt="My family" src="http://localhost/images/my_family.png"/>
    <p/>
    <fb:like></fb:like>
</body>
```

I am running this on JBoss 5.1 on a Windows 7/Intel laptop, and am using both IE9 and Firefix web browsers.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If `http://localhost/Fbtest.jsp` is actually the value you're using, this won't work - Facebook needs to contact that URL to read the tags, so it needs to be a publicly accessible URL

Comment: Thank you. I have moved the page to a server that Facebook can access - I have verified this by running the page through the FB debugger. However I still get the plain, old Like button.

Comment: That should work OK, but until the page has been liked once there won't be a popup because the metadata is only stored after the first 'like' (as far as I know), and isn't available quickly enough to be displayed at the first 'like'

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem exactly. After the first Like, the pop-up included the title, description and image that I had included in the open graph tags.